# how to block my app from sending an intent to other app?

Tags: android, android-intent

i want to block my app from starting other installed app by sending an intent.

there is any way to block all intent that are sent from my app to a specific package?

there is any way to block intent?

Comment: how do you create the intent? where are you receiving it?

Comment: Just don't send the intent? If it's your app..then what's the issue? Do you have any more context that you can give?

Comment: Why just not program the intents not to start? or just remove them?

Comment: OP only wants to block a specific app from the list a user sees for that intent.

Comment: i do not want to send the intent, i added some library an component to my app that they send intent and start other app.

Answer (score 0):

I think its not possible.

When you create an implicit intent, the Android system finds the appropriate component to start by comparing the contents of the intent to the intent filters declared in the manifest file of other apps on the device. If the intent matches an intent filter, the system starts that component and delivers it the Intent object. If multiple intent filters are compatible, **the system displays a dialog so the user can pick which app to use.** (You can select your component here, that's all you can do if you want to use that lib)

continue reading [@android.documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-filters.html) ...

found it interesting as well ...

Comment: i just want to block sending intents to com.xxx.xxxx package for example.

Answer (score 0):

> i added some library an component to my app that they send intent and start other app

Then get rid of that library. You have no means of preventing that library from starting activities, sending broadcasts, starting services, etc.

Comment: but i need that library.

Comment: @arsenal: Talk to the author of the library and ask if there is a way to reconfigure the library to not do this stuff. Or, if it is open source, modify the library to not do this stuff. Or, live with it.

Comment: @arsenal: Then you will have to live with it.